# removing duplicate subsets of rows

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a list of stocks in an index sorted by date, and I'm trying to remove all rows in which the previous row has the same stock code.  This will give a dataframe of the initial index and all dates that there was a change to the index

In my working example, I'll use names instead of the date column, and some numbers.

At first, I thought I could remove the rows by using subset() and !duplicated

```
name <- c("Joe","Mary","Sue","Frank","Carol","Bob","Kate","Jay")
num <- c(1,2,2,1,2,2,2,3)
num2 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame(name,num,num2)
dfnew <- subset(df, !duplicated(df[,2]))
```

However, this might not work in the case where a stock is removed from the list and then later replaced.   So, in my working example, the desired output are the rows of Joe, Mary, Frank, Carol and Jay.

Next I created a function to tell if the index changes.  The input of the function is row number:

```
#------ function to tell if there is a change in the row subset-----#
df2 <- as.matrix(df)
ChangeDay <- function(x){
       Current <- df2[x,2:3]                 
   Prev <- df2[x-1,2:3]
   if (length(Current)  != length(Prev))
      NewList <- true
   else
      NewList <- length(which(Current==Prev))!=length(Current)
   return(NewList)
}
```

Finally, I attempt to create a loop to remove the desired rows.  I'm new to programming, and I struggle with loops.  I'm not sure what the best way is to pre-allocate memory when the dimensions of my final output is unknown.   All the books I've looked at only give trivial loop examples.  Here is my latest attempt:

```
result <- matrix(data=NA,nrow=nrow(df2),ncol=3)   #pre allocate memory
tmp <- as.numeric(df2)    #store the original data
changes <- 1
for (i in 2:nrow(df2)){    #always keep row 1, thus the loop starts at row 2

   if(ChangeDay(i)==TRUE){

     result[i,] <-tmp[i]     #store the row in result if ChangeDay(i)==TRUE
     changes <- changes + 1    #increment counter
   }
}
result <- result[1:changes,]
```

Thansk for your help, and any additional general advice on loops is appreciated!

Comment: as general advice, I'd recommend you read R inferno http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: To me when first starting with programming in R, I thought loops were the easy part. It was just a logical way to do things I needed without a huge knowledge of built-in functions in R. Since then I've picked up experience with all kinds of different functions and tricks that makes everything quicker. The functions are more abstract than a for loop, so it will take some getting used to. That being said, I am still not a strong programmer and rely on loops more than I probably should. But as long as you keep that to yourself, the people here won't judge you ;) (only half joking)

Comment: also, I'm not really sure what you want out of your other two chunks of code.

Comment: Thanks for the R inferno link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you want to do. But I guess :

```
df[c(1,diff(df$num)) !=0,]
   name num num2
1   Joe   1    1
2  Mary   2    1
4 Frank   1    1
5 Carol   2    1
8   Jay   3    1
```

Comment: This solved the working example.  My real data has over 100 columns, so I'm trying to understand and generalize what you've done.  Looks like the "1" keeps the first row, and the diff function removes the rows I want removed.  I tried df[c(1,diff(df[c(2:3),]) !=0,]   to try extending the diff function to multiple columns, but I get an error.  Error: unexpected ']' in "df.....